# Change position of search form in Store Locator Library for Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using [Store Locator Library](http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/panel.html) for Maps API.
How to move search form to another part of DOM?

Comment: What does _your_ code look like? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `input` to wherever you'd like it to be...